# Create ERC721 with media file

Tags: solidity, erc-721, ipfs, nft

I want to create an ERC721 smart-contract.
The token will be associated to a png file.

The users will see there tokens in metamask and i want to display there png files in metamask (this is very important).

Here is what i've tried:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721
{
   using Counters for Counters.Counter;
   Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

   constructor() public ERC721("My Token", "MY2") 
   {
      awardItem(msg.sender,'https://mywebsite/metadata1.json'); 
   }

   function awardItem(address recipient, string memory metadata) public returns (uint256)
   {
       _tokenIds.increment();
       uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
       _mint(recipient, newItemId);
       _setTokenURI(newItemId, metadata);
       return newItemId;
   }
}
```

Here is the content of metadata1.json :

```
{
  "name": "My Token1",
  "hash": "https://mywebsite/myimage1.png" 
}
```

Everything works fine. I can see the png file of the first token in the owner wallet after smartcontract's deployment.

- I had to configure my collectible in metamask app: I had to set contract's address but also token id. Metamask can not scan all tokens i own in this contract ?
- Is there a way to put metadata on chain (in a storage variable) instead of an external json file ?
- I have tried to put png file on ipfs. I have tried pinata and i have tried to put an url like: ipfs//<image_hash>. It does not work. The picture is not displayed in metamask in this case. Any idea ?

Thanks a lot